# OneToMany relationship with User

Tags: jhipster

I just started a project with the code generator "Jhipster". I'm trying to make a OneToMany relationship with the "User" relationship. I've looked at a lot of topics already but I can't find any working answers. Do you have any ideas? I even tried to go through an intermediate relationship but nothing works.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create relationships between your model entities and the special entity User. But you have to take into consideration the restrictions of this entity. As it appears in the JHipster [documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/):

> Tip: the User entity
>
> Please note that the User entity, which is handled by JHipster, is
> specific. You can do:
>
> **many-to-one** relationships to this entity (a Car can have a many-to-one relationship to a User). This will generate a specific
> query in your new entity repository, so you can filter your entity on
> the current security user, which is a common requirement. On the
> generated Angular/React client UI you will have a dropdown in Car to
> select a User.
>
> **many-to-many** and **one-to-one** relationships to the User entity, but the other entity must be the owner of the relationship (a Team can
> have a many-to-many relationship to User, but only the team can
> add/remove users, and a user cannot add/remove a team). On the
> Angular/React client UI, you will also be able to select a User in a
> multi-select box.
>
> When using the UAA authentication type, you can only create
> relationships to the User entity if the related entity is also within
> the UAA microservice.

Comment: Hello juanmgar and thank you for your answer. After reflexion, i need a ManyToMany relationship and your answer help me. I never put an owner in the relationship and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much